# Shifting elements of a container and filling shifted place with default constructed elements

Tags: c++

For example:
`c = {"aaa", "aaa"}` -> `c >> 1` -> `c = {"", "aaa"}`

I thought I can use `std::shift_right` but it uses `std::move` internally and moved from object are left unspecified state:

```cpp
 std::vector<bool> bv(5, true);
 std::shift_left(begin(bv), end(bv), 4); // prints 1 1 1 1 1
```

After some search come up with this but wonder is there a better solution:

```cpp
 std::rotate(begin(bv), begin(bv) + 4, end(bv));
 std::fill_n(begin(bv), 4, false); // 0 0 0 0 1
```

Comment: Sooo, just write a `for` loop? `moved from object are left unspecified state` so construct them?

Comment: Maybe you're right, a for loop is way to go. I somewhat became a little picky, and wonder is there an alg. to make this in one step. My actual use case is a little more involved but yeah

Answer (score 4):

While it is true that `std::move()` leaves objects in an unspecified state, you can still assign a new value to the element. So the following is perfectly fine.

```
constexpr size_t N = 4;
std::vector<bool> bv(5, true);
std::shift_right(bv.begin(), bv.end(), N); // prints 1 1 1 1 1 (but the first 4 elements are in an unspecified state).
std::fill_n(bv.begin(), 4, false); // 0 0 0 0 1
```

Comment: thanks @deev, maybe i missed, but can you elaborate what does your answer makes different than my question above?

Comment: @syntaxonly: I was just mentioning that you don't need to use `std::rotate`. You can use `std::shift_right` and `std::fill_n` because assigning to a moved from element is well defined behavior (provided the move and copy assignment operators are properly defined). Unfortunately, I can't think of a standard library algorithm that will accomplish what you want in a single iteration. Also, I think you meant to write `shift_right` instead of `shift_left` in your original code.